# Angular-ui validation not working in model window

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid, angular-ui-modal

I am working on AngularJS with ui-grid. In the grid when i edit a row I am opening a modal window like this

```
$scope.editRow = function(row){     
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl : contextPath+ '/row/edit',
        controller : 'EditController',
        size : 'lg',
        scope: $scope,
        resolve : {
            result : function() {
                return row;
            }
        }
    }); 
    modalInstance.result.then(function() {
    .......
    });
}
```

and the model window gets  open with the row details after calling Editcontroller default function. Until this point it is working fine. 
Now i am trying to do the validation on the opened modal window using AngularUI and the validation is not working.  Below is my UI page where the validation is not working

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">      
    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
    <h3 align="center">Edit Row Details</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="myform" ng-submit="submitForm(myform.$valid)" novalidate>
            <!-- Content Start -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group required"
                            ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myform.name.$invalid && !myform.name.$pristine }">
                            <label for="name" class="control-label"> Name
                            </label>
                            <div>
                                <input type="text" name="myform.name" class="form-control input-sm"
                                    ng-model="myform.name" placeholder="Name"
                                     required />
                                     <p ng-show="myform.name.$invalid && !myform.name.$pristine" class="help-block"> Name is required.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" ng-model="myform.save"  ng-disabled="myform.$invalid"
                                    class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(myform)">EDIT</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <!-- Content End -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Somebody please help me  how to do the validation. one more thing if i open the modal window normally the validation is working but i have the issue when i edit the row. I think this is a scope issue and the child scope is not getting bind. Your help is very much appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am able to find the solution

in EditController add below code

```
$scope.form={};
```

and your form should have form.myform  like this

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
    <h3 align="center">Edit Row Details</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="form.myform"
        ng-submit="submitForm(form.myform.$valid)" novalidate>
        <!-- Content Start -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group required"
            ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.myform.name.$invalid && !form.myform.name.$pristine }">
            <label for="name" class="control-label"> Name </label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="myform.name"
                    class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="myform.name"
                    placeholder="Name" required />
                <p  ng-show="form.myform.name.$invalid && !form.myform.name.$pristine"
                    class="help-block">Name is required.</p>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
            <button type="submit" ng-model="myform.save" ng-disabled="form.myform.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary"
                    ng-click="edit(myform)">EDIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!-- Content End -->
</form>
</div>
```

I am posting this becoz it may be helpful someone..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the form name in the name of the input, it's within a form so the input is bound to that form already. I'd also recommend binding your ng-model to another object on your scope (below I've used model) rather then the form itself.

You would write it like this.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group required"
        ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myform.name.$invalid && !myform.name.$pristine }">
         <label for="name" class="control-label"> Name </label>
         <div>
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control input-sm"
                                ng-model="model.name" placeholder="Name"
                                 required />
               <p ng-show="myform.name.$invalid && !myform.name.$pristine" class="help-block"> Name is required.</p>

                      </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Also I'd change the ng-submit to the following

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="myform" ng-submit="myform.$valid && submitForm()" novalidate>
```

Comment: It is still not working. i think it is related to scope issue which is not bind to the modal window..

Comment: Can you print out the myform object `{{myform}}` and provide the result.

Comment: {{myform}}   is printing  this {"name":"raju"}

Comment: Are you able to produce a jsfiddle or plunkr replicating this issue?

Comment: No i am not able to create the plunkr

Comment: I think the scope is not getting bind to the form. when i save the form i am just getting the values but not other form values like valid, prinstine etc...